# Ubuntu Server doesn’t boot when kernel is in RAID 1

Tags: boot, server, grub2, 20.04, raid

I have set up a barebones Ubuntu 20.04.2 server and I have a software RAID (in Ubuntu). I have mounted this raid array at `/` and I've also put a USB drive in the server, in which I have `/boot/efi`. Whenever I try to boot into the USB it shows me GRUB.

If I type `exit` in GRUB, it shows a message saying:

```
Boot failed: Ubuntu
```

If I do it one more time, it says the same thing, then the third time it shows

```
StartImage failed: Load error
```

and gets stuck there.

How can I boot the server when kernel is in RAID 1? I am fine with reinstalling my Ubuntu server (as I can’t even get into it).

Comment: If the server has hardware RAID controller, try disabling it and see if that works. Some servers with RAID cards will not allow the boot-loader be installed with the card disabled anyway. Software RAID works best without hardware RAID controller onboard.

Comment: The thing is that I’m also using the hardware raid controller but it’s for a different array to be mounted at a different place on the same Ubuntu install. The raid array that is mounted at / is not attached to the hardware raid contoller.

Comment: @guest0197 Why would you want to use software raid on a server? It sounds like the mdadm driver is not being inserted on boot.  You can find some other distros AKA not Ubuntu that rely more heavily on RAID and support it during the initial setup.  They will ensure your drives are formatted correctly and all flags are set for software RAID.  I would still recommend hardware RAID in a true server setup. It also sounds like you are migrating BAREMETAL and likely there  are some issues from whatever other BAREMETAL you are coming from. (/dev/XXXX and /dev/XXXX mapping issues)

Comment: @guest0197 For the Software RAID, where is it connected? It would be helpful to understand what BAREMETAL configuration you are using in order to help you better.

Comment: I'm not migrating anything. It's a dell r720 that I'm putting this on. There are a couple of hard drives attached to the front of it, which goes to the hardware raid controller (h710 mini). I have created a vd for this in the bios. There are two pcie ssds (not connected to raid controller) which are for the software raid 1, which is where the os should be. There is also a usb stick inside the server which has the boot loader. In the UEFI options it shows up as Ubuntu, but it just leads to Grub. Also, what other operating systems do you recommend? Would Debian be a good option?

Comment: @guest0197 well, just to make sure I understand, you install Ubuntu from some device unaltered to the 2 PCIE SSDs in software RAID 1, without the hardware controller used at all during the setup, then still experience this problem? I have less experience with the same hardware setup than others, but I'm guessing if you are trying to use both hard and soft raid during setup, that's where you are running into problems. I would do a full /root /home /boot install on the software raid, then map and edit fstab accordingly after first boot to fix hardware RAID availability. Other distros in next..

Comment: Software RAID requires kernel support. At boot time, `grub` is trying to find a kernel to load. Why do you think `grub` supports Software RAID?

Comment: No, I used the hardware controller during the setup, but I did install Ubuntu from a totally different usb drive. Before I try to set up Ubuntu server again, should I put /boot on the pcie ssd and the /boot/efi on the usb? Ubuntu server installer doesn't show me the option to add a boot device from a software raid.

Comment: I was thinking of a distro that I used back when I was trying to software raid some IDE drives on some really old hardware like "Python" in the name and it was stopped in devel. around version 9.0 (think its a different snake name or starts with P) but its whole focus was on making soft raid work out of the box with no worries and a GUI for setup.  Only suggestion I have for you is to try Fedora and see if you can get the software raid working using the automated (guided) partitioning of it.  When you are done, you can wipe the partitions for the Ubuntu installer, but don't delete the tables.

Comment: to waltinator's post, I believe I was able to get around that in the past by creating two "/dev/sda1" and "/dev/sdb1" (for boot devices) the same sometimes requires due diligence to keep them synced.  With software raid, you just make sure that "/dev/sda2" and "/dev/sdb2" are the target for RAID 0 or 1

Comment: I don't know that you want to use the server installer either. You probably will have to write the partition edits to disk first and get them flagged right before you launch or relaunch the installer to get it to see the software raid. above sda1 and sdb1 must both be mapped to boot or another way is map one to /boot and the other to /boot/efi when I say launch or relaunch I'm referring to a full reboot of the installer after properly partitioning the drives whether its the fedora installer or another

Comment: if you use software raid or lvm (lvm might make it easier in some ways and harder in others) you will still likely have to issue some terminal commands in the live usb installer environment prior partitioning in the setup. Some might illogically include installing programs with apt-get that you would think are by standard already included or loaded. (luks lvm fakeraid mdadm etc)

Comment: If you can get to a working solution, I will post an answer with all the forum guidelines intact.  We can work together to get to that solution as I'm sure you aren't the first to run into this problem with newer server solutions(hardware). I'm glad you posted this question and am happy to help. Please DM me at gm2500main2@gmail.com if you can't get a timely reply.

Comment: I actually just got it to work without having to use anything else other than the Ubuntu installer. All that I changed was putting /boot and /boot/efi (instead of just the efi directory) on the usb drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by putting the entire /boot directory on the usb drive. Afterwards it would boot from the usb drive. I'm still not 100% sure why the Ubuntu live server installer doesn't let you boot off of a software raid, but I'm not too worried about that. The only concern that I have with this is the usb drive failing because it's not redundant in any way.

Comment: I don't think you can boot from a software raid because the software isn't loaded yet to use the raid.  If you're worried about the usb failing just make a clone of it; I don't think it is modified outside of kernel updates.